# Configure fontsize of TEntry

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to change the fontsize of a ttk::entry widget but it doesn't work (the fontsizes of the label and the button widget are displayed correct). That's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish
ttk::style theme use default 
font create MyFont -family Helvetica -size 24
ttk::style configure TButton -font MyFont
ttk::style configure TLabel -font MyFont
ttk::style configure TEntry -font MyFont
puts [ttk::style lookup TEntry -font]
ttk::entry .en
ttk::button .bt -text "OK"
ttk::label .lb -text "Hello"
pack .en .lb .bt
```

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventional wisdom seems to be that you can't change the font in an entry in this way. You need to use the regular `.en config -font MyFont`.